# Microfocus cics xctl commarea

Tags: cics, microfocus

In MICROFOCUS:

PROG100 uses this command to transfer to PROG200.

It is PASSING WORKING-STORAGE FIELD.

EXEC CICS  XCTL PROGRAM ('PROG200')
                  COMMAREA (WORKING-STORAGE-FIELD) LENGTH (199) END-EXEC.

PROG200 receives garbage in the DFHCOMMAREA.

Any ideas how to fix this? Maybe directives?

Comment: The WORKING-STORAGE-FIELD and DFHCOMMAREA are the same size.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your WORKING-STORAGE-FIELD is valid and properly initialized then the receiving programs DFHCOMMAREA should have the correct value.
Remember, the DFHCOMMAREA comes after the DFHEIBLK definition in the Linkage Section.